# Can't build a docker image because of pre-depedency issues

Tags: docker

I am trying to setup a docker image for work, but I am running into issues with libssl1.0.0. When I run `docker-compose build`,  this is the output I get back

```
 ---> Running in 1d506ae8e916
dpkg: regarding libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u11_amd64.deb containing libssl1.0.0:amd64, pre-dependency problem:
 libssl1.0.0 pre-depends on multiarch-support
  multiarch-support is not installed.

dpkg: error processing archive libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u11_amd64.deb (--install):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing libssl1.0.0:amd64
Selecting previously unselected package libssl1.0.0:amd64.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u11_amd64.deb
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u11_amd64.deb' returned a non-zero code:
```

I have mutliarch-support installed, I even `sudo apt-get remove multiarch-support` and reinstalled it. Same with `libssl1.0.0`, I even removed `libssl1.1.0`.

Comment: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/issues/5893

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the package in your image not in your host. Install multiarch-support in one previous RUN command than the one that gives the error.

Comment: Thank you this was the issue